# Does WriteableBitmap has new features in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, writeablebitmap

and if someone could give me an example on how to use it, with a stream? (not sure how that works) I know how to create a `BitmapImage` from an `URI` now I need to convert this image to a `WriteableBitmap`, but I get a null exception error with something like this:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.example.com/example.png"));
WriteableBitmap newImage = new WriteableBitmap(image);
```

Comment: Do you want to fill the WriteableBitmap with a PNG image from a web file or from a resource stream?

Comment: I have a PNG on a webpage that I want to use to fill the WriteableBitmap, I don't care how. But I need to modify the image (at pixel level, PNG's 8 bits would have made it easier) is it better to use a resource stream?

Answer (score 4):

In short: Nope, there are no new features in Silverlight 4. The [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com) tries to compensate the missing functionality.

Regarding your real problem:
You should add a handler to the [BitmapImage.ImageFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imagefailed(v=VS.95).aspx) event to see if there's an error when the image should be downloaded. And you you should create the WriteableBitmap in the [ImageOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imageopened(v=VS.95).aspx) event handler.

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.example.com/example.png"));
WriteableBitmap newImage = null;
image.ImageOpened += (s, e) => newImage = new WriteableBitmap(image);
```

Please also note that cross-domain references are permitted. See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473(v=VS.95).aspx) for details. **You should put the image into the Web Project's ClientBin folder and use a relative path instead.**

As an alternative you can also compile the image into the assembly as resource and load it from there. The [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com) has an extension method to make this task a bit easier. But keep in mind that this blows the assembly size up and the initial XAP loading time will increase.

```
// Load an image from the calling Assembly's resources only by passing the relative path
var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromResource("example.png");
```

Comment: I tried your idea, now I don't get an error but I don't get an image either.. that means that the server doesn't allow cross domain requests? and thus there's no way I can do it?

Comment: Check this two links for Cross Domain calls:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/12/12/silverlight-crossdomain-access-workarounds.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2008/03/30/some-tips-on-cross-domain-calls.aspx

Comment: Neither is working for me. The first code block never have the ImageOpened handler get called; The second throws an exception. I'm using Silverlight 5.